# Runge-Kutta 4th order with 2th order ODE error

Tags: java, function, for-loop, ode, runge-kutta

I recently made a code to solve a RLC circuit problem, with a 2th order ODE with Runge-Kutta method, but the code I made doens't match the result with standart result ODE for example, with a **5ohm** resistor (R), **10mF** capacitor (C), **1H** inductor (L), **5v** with initial voltage [v(0)], **0A** for the electric current [i(0)] and **0.05s** for the time (t), with **100 iteration** I got **1.5163v**, and with the code I got **3.75v**, i can't see what I'm doing wrong. Here are the ODE equations:

[image: ODE equations]

And here is the equation to find the initial value of **v'(0)**=**w(0)**:

[image: w(0) initial value]

Now, the Runge-Kutta method:

[image: Runge-Kutta 4th order]

And finally the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<iteracao;i++, hX+=h){

        tensaofSec=tensaof;
        wTV=wf;
        wT=wf;

        //Runge-Kutta para a funcao v'(t) e w'(t)

        l1=h*funcaoV;
        k1=h*funcaoW;

        wT=(wf+(k1/2));
        wTV=(wf+(k1/2));
        tensaofSec=(tensaof+(l1/2));

        k2=h*funcaoW;
        l2=h*funcaoV;

        wT=(wf+(k2/2));
        wTV=(wf+(k2/2));
        tensaofSec=(tensaof+(l2/2));

        k3=h*funcaoW;
        l3=h*funcaoV;

        wT=(wf+k3);
        wTV=(wf+k3);
        tensaofSec=(tensaof+l3);

        k4=h*funcaoW;
        l4=h*funcaoV;

        wf=wf+((k1+(2*k2)+(2*k3)+k4)/6);

        tensaof=tensaof+((l1+(2*l2)+(2*l3)+l4)/6);
    }
```

[The complete function for calculate the final voltage](https://pastebin.com/pwbHz5MY)

Comment: What type do have `funcaoW`, `funcaoV` and `tensaof`? Your code assumes some macro-like qualities, I'm not sure that Java has such facilities.

Comment: funcaoW, funcaoV and tensaof are double values.

Comment: Then you are integrating a constant and should thus get linear functions as result.

Comment: @LutzL so, what should I do?

Comment: Make them function calls, possibly via lambda constructs. `funcaoV(wT)` and `funcaoW(tensaofSec,wT)`. Whatever did you intent the difference between `wT` and `wTV` to be?

Comment: @LutzL  because `wTV` it's the value of W for the function `funcaoV` and `wT` it's the value of W for the function `funcaoW`

Comment: But as of yet, they are not functions, they are just doubles that are constant inside the loop. And the two w values are always the same, so why have the same number under a different name?

Comment: @LutzL I understand now, so I have do create functions called `public double functionW(double tensaoSec, double wT)` and `public double functionV(double wT)` ?

Comment: Yes. It would probably help to store the computation results in arrays so that you can plot the full solution and compare against the theoretically expected behavior.

Comment: Thaks @LutzL I write them with function, and only altered inside them, and worked. I wanted to plot a graph with the values of voltage, but I don't know how to import the array `tensaof`.